# Welcher deutsche Ausdruck bedeutet "make directory"?

Tags: technical-terminology

Wie drückt man sich aus 《machen 》en deutsch?

Auf Computern ist der Linuxbefehl `mkdir` eine Abkürzung für den englischen Ausdruck "***make directory***".

Welcher deutsche Ausdruck bedeutet "make directory"

- Erstellen Sie einen leeren Manilla-Ordner
- Machen Sie ein neues leeres Blatt Papier, das in der Mitte gefaltet ist
- Erstellen Sie eine Papiermappe.
- Leerbehälter für Akten herstellen oder bereitstellen.

Comment: Die Kernfrage hier scheint der geeignete Begriff für ein Verzeichnis bzw. einen Ordner zu sein. Da entsprechende Computersysteme im deutschen Sprachraum schon seit geraumer Zeit verbreitet sind, ist es naheliegend, dass Wörterbücher dafür eventuell bereits Einträge enthalten könnten. Mir ist jedenfalls etwas unklar, wie beispielsweise der Übersetzungsvorschlag "leeres Blatt Papier, das in der Mitte gefaltet ist" zustande gekommen sein könnte.

Comment: Woher kommen die Übersetzungsvorschläge?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Vom Blick auf die Icons her, wahrscheinlich.

Comment: @ORMapper Wenn ein amerikanischer Computerprogrammierer mit einem anderen amerikanischen Computerprogrammierer spricht, verwenden die beiden Amerikaner Wörter und Ausdrücke, die die breite Öffentlichkeit nicht verwendet. In Amerika sind viele Menschen nicht in der Lage, Linux-Befehle oder Unix-Befehle zu schreiben. Für amerikanische Programmierer hat `mkdir` die gleiche Bedeutung wie `eine Papiermappe aufräumen`. Amerikaner sagen etwas Ähnliches wie "neuen leeren Ordner erstellen"

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon Mag sein, aber ist das ein Grund um eine neue Sprache zu erfinden die man genauso lernen muss wie die bisherige? Wer nicht in der Lage ist mkdir zu schreiben und zu wissen was das bedeutet, der kann auch keinen anderen Satz in genau der benötigten Formulierung schreiben. Jemand der grundlegende Verständnisprobleme hat setzt sich sowieso nicht mit der Shell auseinander. Da wäre eine GUI besser geeignet, statt ein Wrapper für die Shell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Die gängige übersetzung für "directory" is "Verzeichnis".
Entsprechend wird "make directory" mit

> Verzeichnis erstellen

übersetzt. Zum beispiel hier auf der Webseite von IBM: https://www.ibm.com/docs/de/aix/7.2?topic=directories-creating-mkdir-command

> Mit dem Befehl mkdir können Sie Verzeichnisse erstellen, die Sie für den Parameter Verzeichnis angeben.

Bei grafischen Benutzeroberflächen scheint sich auch

> Neuer Ordner

etabliert zu haben.

Comment: Zum Thema "Ordner" vs. "Verzeichnis" (bzw. dem englischen Äquivalent "folder" vs "directory") sind die Antworten zu dieser Frage auf [retrocomputing.se] ganz aufschlussreich: [*When was the term ‘directory’ replaced by ‘folder’?*](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/when-was-the-term-directory-replaced-by-folder)

Answer (score 7):

Debian has a [manpages-l10n](https://snapshot.debian.org/package/manpages-l10n/4.18.0-1/) package. You can read the German translations online at https://manpages.debian.org/testing/manpages-de/index.html. For `mkdir`, it says

> mkdir - Verzeichnisse erstellen

Comment: Warum antwortest du in einer Fremdsprache? Die Frage wurde in einem Deutsch-Forum in deutscher Sprache gestellt. Daher sollte auch die Antwort in Deutsch erfolgen. Siehe auch https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/830/1487

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Weil der Fragende sich selbst als Amerikaner identifiziert hat und offensichtlich Verständnisschwierigkeiten mit deutschen Begriffen hat.

Answer (score -2):

> ist der Linuxbefehl `mkdir` eine Abkürzung

Nein! Und zwar "NEIN!" aus mehreren Gründen:

Erstens ist "mkdir" kein "Linuxbefehl", sondern ein "UNIX"-Befehl. Er ist seit Anfang an in UNIX wie auch in "UNIX-ähnlichen" Betriebssystemen (dazu zählt Linux) vorhanden und sein Vorhandensein ist (für UNIX-Systeme) vorgeschrieben durch den sogenannten POSIX-Standard, den Systeme, die sich "UNIX" nennen wollen, erfüllen müssen. (<sub>Für den Fall, daß Sie eine mehr technische Beschreibung wünschen: genaugenommen ist "mkdir" - das Kommando - nur ein bißchen Drumherum um einen sehr grundlegenden *System Call*, eine Funktion aus der Standard-Bibliothek (stdlib) namens `mkdir()`, der seinerseits ein Directory anlegt. Das Kommando ist nur ein wenig Code um diese Funktion herum, der die Kommandozeile auswertet, einen Rückgabewert ans Betriebssystem zurückgibt und dgl. mehr.</sub>)

Zweitens ist "mkdir" keine Abkürzung - es ist ein Befehl. Ja, der Befehl dient dazu, ein Directory (je nachdem auch mehrere Directories) anzulegen, aber der Befehl "mkdir" ist nicht die "Abkürzung für *make directory*", sondern hat nie anders als eben so geheißen. Der griechische Buchstabe π für das Verhältnis von Kreisumfang und -durchmesser kommt from griechischen Wort "περίμετρος" ("perímetros", Umfang), dennoch ist π keine "Abkürzung", sondern heißt so, wie es eben heißt. Mutatis mutandis gilt das auch für "mkdir" bzw. "mkdir()".

Drittens: die Frage der Übersetzung technischer Fachbegriffe ist eine diffizile und im Allgemeinen wird darüber ziemlich viel gestritten. Klar kann man "Directory" mit "Verzeichnis" oder "Ordner" übersetzen - aber dann sollte man konsequent sein und auch alle anderen Begriffe ins Deutsche übersetzen.

Nur damit das klar ist: "ins Deutsche übersetzen" heißt dann nicht, die englischen durch lateinische und griechische Fremdwörter zu ersetzen! Fremdwort ist Fremdwort! Dann heißt es eben nicht mehr "Filesystem", sondern "Sachverhaltsansammlungsanordnung", denn ein "File" ist dann eben nicht eine "Datei", sondern eine Ansammlung von <s>Daten</s>Sachverhalten und das griechische "System" wird zur deutschen "Anordnung". Auf die Übersetzung von "Major Number" und "Minor Number" (das sind beides Eigenschaften eines Files in einem UNIX-Filesystem) bin ich gespannt.

Übrigens: Die hier bereits zitierte IBM hat im "Handbuch für Datenverarbeitung" einmal den "Stack Pointer" zu "Kellerstapelspeicherzeiger" übersetzt. Dagegen ist die "Sachverhaltsansammlungsanordnung" geradezu <s>zivil</s>nichtinderarmeeverwendet. Mannesmann-Tally hat in einer seiner Dokumentationen festgestellt, daß der Drucker durch "Fluchtfolgen" gesteuert wird - was stimmt, wenn man sich die "Escape-Sequenzen" vom Gebrauch abspart. Leider hat mir die Kenntnis aller dieser Feinheiten nichts genützt, als ich mal eine IBM R/6000 Mod J50 installieren sollte, bei der durch einen unglücklichen Zufall die Firmware auf Deutsch gestellt war. Wertvolle Minuten meines Lebens verbrachte ich mit dem Brüten darüber, was wohl eine "Seitenwechseleinheit" sein soll, bis endlich der Groschen "Paging Device" fiel. Es folgt daraus, daß man dem Übersetzungsbüro IBM nicht allzuviel Vertrauen entgegenbringen sollte - reputable Quellen sehen anders aus.

Unter dem Strich - wenigstens für mich, andere mögen zu anderen Schlüssen kommen - bleibt folgende Erkenntnis: Fremdworte sollte man gebrauchen, wenn das Fremdwort die dargestellte Sache besser und genauer (nuancierter) beschreibt als die deutsche Übersetzung. Karl Kraus hat das mal in der Glosse "Hier wird deutsch gespuckt" etwa so formuliert (ich paraphrasiere hier):

> Man soll nicht von Kretins sprechen, wenn man es mit Trotteln zu tun hat, andererseits hat die Stupidität eine Farbe, die weder durch die Einfalt noch durch die Dummheit vollgültig ersetzt wird.

Insbesondere in der Fachsprache sollte man *etablierte* Begriffe verwenden. Kein Mediziner würde sich die "Luxation" etwa zu "Umrichtung" (das ist die deutsche Übersetzung) übersetzen lassen. Die nennen eine "bakterielle Infektion" auch genau so und nicht etwa "Verseuchung mit Kleinstlebewesen". Warum sollten Informatiker (Sachverhaltsdarstellungswissenschaftler?) sich nicht ihrer Fachsprache - die halt auf Englisch basiert, nicht auf Latein oder Griechisch - bedienen?

Mag sein, daß, wenn man diesen Maßstab zugrundelegt, "Verzeichnis" genausogut die Sache beschreibt, wie "Directory". Für das hier ebenfalls angeführte "Device" ist die Übersetzung "Gerät" schon mindestens fragwürdig (Devices sind auch Dinge, die keine Geräte sind, denn "Device" heißt eben auch "Kunstgriff" oder "Methode". Das, was durch "Device" beschrieben wird, wird durch den englischen Begriff gedeckt, nicht aber durch seine deutsche (Fehl-)Übersetzung. Schon gar nicht sollte man das "Device" durch "Einheit" (siehe oben) übersetzen, weil es genau das eben nicht ist.

Ganz schwierig wird es dann etwa bei der erwähnten "Major Number". Das ist übrigens das da, ich habe es fett markiert:

`root@unixsystem:/> ls -l /dev | tail -n 10
crw-rw-rw-    1 root    system       24, 11 May 10 2022  ttypb
crw-rw-rw-    1 root    system       24, 12 May 10 2022  ttypc
crw-rw-rw-    1 root    system       24, 13 May 10 2022  ttypd
crw-rw-rw-    1 root    system       24, 14 May 10 2022  ttype
crw-rw-rw-    1 root    system       24, 15 May 10 2022  ttypf
crw-r--r--    1 root    system       35,  1 Nov 17 11:02 urandom
crw-------    1 root    system       11,  0 May 10 2022  vio0
crw-------    1 root    system       16,  0 Mar 10 14:24 vty0
drwxr-xr-x    2 root    system          256 May 10 2022  xti
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     system      2,   3 May 10 2022  zero`

Glaubt jemand ernsthaft, das mit "größere Zahl", "Hauptzahl" oder dergleichen übersetzen zu müssen und dann auch noch verstanden zu werden? Was ist mit mit "Pipe(-line)"? "Rohrleitung" gefällig? Solange ich mir jedenfalls im Fernsehen jeden Tag in der Werbung anhören muß, daß ich das Zeug, das man sich in die Haare schmieren soll, brauche, weil es "meine Styles" unterstützt und "alle meine Moves" mitmacht und die "Anti-Aging-Creme" für meine "Skin-Care" unheimlich wichtig sei, solange habe ich kein schlechtes Gewissen, ein Verzeichnis "Directory" zu nennen.

Zum Unterschied von "Verzeichnis" hat nämlich "Directory" als Entität eines Filesystems eine präzise Definition. Darunter versteht man eine exakt festlegte Sache. Unter "Verzeichnis" kann man alles mögliche verstehen. Auch das ist ein Grund, warum zum Beispiel Mediziner von "Pruritus" sprechen, wenn sie "Juckreiz" meinen. Ersterer Begriff ist exakt definiert, letzterer nicht.

PS: offensichtlich habe ich das Leseverständnis nicht korrekt eingeschätzt, deshalb hier für alle, die die implizierte Antwort: *warum muß man es überhaupt übersetzen?* nicht verstanden haben, nochmal explizit:

*Man muß - wenigstens "Directory" - überhaupt nicht übersetzen, weil es ein Fachterminus ist.*

Daß man "make" mit "machen", erzeugen", "erstellen", "produzieren" und dgl. mehr übersetzen kann, sagt einem zwar jedes Wörterbuch, aber sichheitshalber erwähne ich es hier nochmal, damit mir nicht nahcgesagt wird, ich wäre auf die Frage nicht eingegangen.

Comment: Downvote weil die Frage ("Wie sagt man 'make directory' auf Deutsch?") schlicht nicht beantwortet wird. Und über "mkdir ist keine Abkürzung von make directory" könnte man natürlich auch noch hervorragend streiten ...

Comment: Ich dachte, die Antwort "am besten gar nicht, man beläßt es bei 'make directory'" wäre offensichtlich impliziert. Vielleicht habe ich das Leseverständnis überschätzt.

Comment: Gut, man könnte diesen einen kurzen Absatz "Drittens: [...]. Klar kann man "Directory" mit "Verzeichnis" oder "Ordner" übersetzen - aber dann sollte man konsequent sein und auch alle anderen Begriffe ins Deutsche übersetzen." als Antwort auffassen. Ich interpretiere den aber so, dass Du von der Übersetzung abrätst und "Verzeichnis" oder "Ordner" nicht für geeignete Übersetzungen von "directory" (oder "folder") hältst. Aber beide sind nun mal etablierte und korrekte Übersetzungen, von daher wäre die Antwort dann schlicht falsch und ebenso Downvote-würdig.

Comment: Daß ich davon abrate, geht aus: "Mag sein, daß, wenn man diesen Maßstab zugrundelegt, 'Verzeichnis' genausogut die Sache beschreibt, wie 'Directory'." direkt hervor. Wie ich sehe, hast Du diesen Satz völlig richtig verstanden.  Und ich Simpel habe geglaubt, ich hätte das Gegenteil gesagt. Vielen Dank für die Richtigstellung meiner Worte!

Comment: Eine Luxation ist eine Verrenkung. Die vermeintliche Präzision des Fremdwortes ist eine Illusion. Ein *directory* kann ein Telefon- oder Adressbuch sein; auf Englisch wie auf Deutsch entscheidet der Kontext. In den anderen Antworten wurde schon aus einer *manpage* (Handbuchseite) zitiert: *mkdir - Verzeichnisse erstellen*. Damit ist *Verzeichnis* doch genauso Fachsprache wie *directory*?

Comment: @bakunin Ich hätte das Wort 《Abkürzung》 nicht verwenden sollen. Mein Deutsch ist von schlechter Qualität. Ich hätte "mathematische Teilfolge" schreiben sollen. Wenn `σ = "make directory"` und `σ(1) = "m"`, `σ(2) = "a"`, `σ(3) = "k"` et cetra dann haben wir `σ( 1, 3, 6, 7, 8) = "mkdir"`. `"mkdir"` ist eine Unterfolge von `"make directory"`.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Ich habe (offenbar erfolglos) versucht, das Übersetzungsproblem 'Directory'-'Verzeichnis' in das allgemeine Problem "Übersetzung von Fachausdrücken und Vermeidung angemessener Fachsprache" einzubetten. Daß "Verzeichnis" für "Directory" hingeht, habe ich eindeutig gesagt, was willst du noch? Das beantwortet dann aber nicht die Frage, warum man nicht alle Fremdworte (nicht nur die englischen) übersetzt. Daß die "Präzision des Fremdworts" eben keine "Illusion" ist, habe ich am Beispiel "Device" belegt, oder? Ist das nun eine Nuance oder eine Farbschattierung?

Comment: @DavidVogt: Der Punkt ist ja eben nicht, daß "Luxation" die deutsche Übersetzung "Verrenkung" (nach anderen Quellen: "Umrichtung") hat, sondern daß Mediziner eben "Luxation" verwenden! Warum nicht "Verrenkung"? Na, eben, weil sie sich ihres Fachjargons bedienen. Linguisten sagen auch "Verb" und nicht "Tätigkeitswort", die sagen auch "Partizip Präsens" und nicht "Mittelwort der Gegenwart". Warum wohl? Hat der verwendete Jargon vielleicht einen Grund? Und warum verwende ich hier "Jargon" und nicht "Wortgebrauch"? Weils eben doch präziser ist, vom "Jargon" zu sprechen, hm?

Comment: Ich wollte folgenden Satz kritisieren: *Zum Unterschied von "Verzeichnis" hat nämlich "Directory" als Entität eines Filesystems eine präzise Definition. Darunter versteht man eine exakt festlegte Sache. Unter "Verzeichnis" kann man alles mögliche verstehen.* – Fachsprache ist präziser, aber nicht, weil sie Fremdworte benutzt (es gibt ja auch *Hauptsatz, Satzklammer, Lautmalerei, Aktionsart*).

Comment: @bakunin Es existieren durchaus auch im deutschsprachigen Ingenieurwesen etablierte Fachbegriffe für die angeführten Konzepte. Diese sind nicht so weit verbreitet wie die englischen, aber sie sind durchaus in Verwendung, vor allem in Fachbereichen mit starkem regulatorischem Einfluss (z.B. Eisenbahnwesen, aber auch diverse Finanz- und Versicherungsdienstleistungen). Das kann man sinnvoll finden oder auch nicht, aber die Existenz sollte man dem Feld nicht absprechen.

Comment: @bakunin Und dass Wörter aus unterschiedlichen Sprachen nicht exakt gleichen Bedeutungsumfang haben müssen, um geeignete Übersetzungen zu sein, sollte klar sein (ich beziehe mich hier auf den Exkurs zu "device" und "Gerät") - ansonsten wären Übersetzungen generell unmöglich. Und das Beispiel ist erstaunlich, weil doch die Bedeutungen "Kunstgriff" und "Methode" auch in der englischsprachigen Informatikliteratur recht selten gemeint sind, wenn von "device" die Rede ist. (Es gibt natürlich Ausnahmen, z.B. [Duff's Device](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%E2%80%99s_Device)).

Comment: Das hier ist ein Deutsch-Forum. Da geht es um die deutsche Sprache. Was soll all der IT-Kram hier? Das mag ja alles richtig sein, aber danach hat niemand gefragt. Die Frage lautet sinngemäß *»Wie übersetzt man "make directory" ins Deutsche?«* aber keine der beiden möglichen Antworten "Verzeichnis erstellen" oder "Ordner erstellen" steht so in diesem Konvolut. Nicht einmal in dem nachträglich hinzugefügten Schluss steht diese simple Antwort.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Das hier ist ein Deutsch-Forum (müßte das dann nicht richtigerweise *Deutsch-Nachrichtenaustauschplattform* heißen?), aber da Sprache halt manchmal auch irgendeinen Inhalt hat und der nicht ganz zu trennen ist von der Art, *wie* man etwas sagt, steht halt der "ganze IT-Kram" hier, so, wie dort, wo es sich ums Kochen dreht, halt auch hin und wieder Küchenweisheiten vorkommen. Und davon abgesehen: dir richtige Antwort auf die "sinngemäße Frage" "wie übersetzt man..." lautet: mit einem Wörterbuch. Das hätte sicher weitergeholfen.

Comment: Ein wenig kann ich dem Rant folgen und würde auch Karl Kraus nicht widersprechen, aber Konsequenz ist keineswegs gefordert (Konsequenz ist keine Tugend) so dass ich morgens "Festplatte" sagen kann und abends "Compiler". Je länger es Computer gibt, desto populärer werden die Eindeutschungen, auch wenn es die sperrigsten Begriffe nicht schaffen. Beim "ich habe downgeloadet" oder "gedownloadet" offenbart sich der Vorteil d. deutschen. Außerdem ist `mkdir` ein Linuxbefehl, weil es ein Befehl ist, der auf Linux verfügbar ist. Dass er aus der Unixwelt stammt ist ein Indiz dafür, nicht dagegen.